# What does "statsTemplate: (params: any) => string;" means?

Tags: typescript

am starting in Typescript and found a syntax I can't handle with the documentation:

```
statsTemplate: (params: any) => string;
```

Comment: It means statsTemplate is a function which accepts an argument called params of any type and returns a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it is easier to explain a type by implementing it:

```
var statsTemplate = function(params: any) : string {
    return 'Hello World';
};
```

This is the implementation of:

```
(params: any) => string;
```

Answer (score 2):

As a whole, this statement defines so-called 'Function Type Literal' (section 3.5.5 *Function Type Literals*):

> A function type literal defines an object type that contains a single
>   call signature.
>
> `FunctionType: ( ParameterListopt ) => ReturnType`

In other words, here you define a type named `statsTemplate` that (obviously) represents functions returning values of `string` type - and taking a single param of any type... which is actually a special type in TypeScript (section 3.1 *The Any Type*):

> The `Any` type is used to represent any JavaScript value. A value of the
>   `Any` type supports the same operations as a value in JavaScript and no
>   static type checking is performed for operations on Any values.
>   Specifically, properties of any name can be accessed through an `Any`
>   value and `Any` values can be called as functions or constructors with
>   any argument list.

As you see, it's actually well described in the documentation ([**PDF**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf)).